# not sure where the comma is missing

Tags: sql, insert

```
INSERT into manufactures (man_id, man_name, address, social_media_available)
    VALUES (seq_manufactures.NEXTVAL, 'ALLIANCE INC',
    address_type('123 MEYNELL ROAD', 'LEICESTER', 'UK'),
    social_media_varray_type (
        social_media_type ('TWITTER', 'ALLIANCE'),
        social_media_type ('FACEBOOK', 'ALLIANCE'),
        social_media_type ('INSTAGRAM', 'ALLIANCE'));
```

Comment: Have you tried formatting your code so it's more readable?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  What are `social_media_type` and `social_media_varray_type`?

Comment: Remove all the code and add one column per iteration. Then you'll get the entire statement or be *sure where the comma is missing*

Answer (score 3):

Your'e missing a parenthesis at the end of your statement :

> social_media_varray_type (
> social_media_type ('TWITTER', 'ALLIANCE'),
> social_media_type ('FACEBOOK', 'ALLIANCE'),
> social_media_type ('INSTAGRAM', 'ALLIANCE')));